Is it safe to replace F40T12 with F32T8?
Fixture had F40T12 fluorescent bulbs in it that have gone bad.  Is it safe to replace with new F32T8 fluorescent bulbs which I already have on hand or should I go buy F40T12's?

Does the ballast say it can drive a T8? The connectors are slightly different, too.


Fixture had F40T12 fluorescent bulbs in it that have gone bad. Is it safe to replace with new F32T8 fluorescent bulbs which I already have on hand or should I go buy F40T12's?

Is it safe?  Sure, but it isn't going to work. If it lights at all, performance will be bad, and bulb life will be very short.
T8 and T12 are mechanically compatible, but not electrically compatible.
If you want to use T8 real fluorescent tubes, get T8 ballasts. They are VERY good - just like steam locomotives and battleships got fantastically good right near the end.  They are silent, don't flicker, and don't struggle to start. Those can be had in the $20 range.
Your other option is to convert to LED, and here, if you are able to replace a ballast you are also able to bypass a ballast, so use double-ended ballast-bypass types (aka type B double-ended).
If not, use "Universal" (Type AB) LEDs - later if the ballast fails, you can have someone bypass the ballast without having to replace the LEDs.


That would depend on the ballast, if it's one that supports both
types. Note that most ballasts only support one type of bulb, though.
Or you replace the ballast to make it compatible with the newer type
bulb (no need for both.)
Or you bypass the ballast and install LED replacement tubes (direct
wire type.)

I tend to avoid the type of LED replacement that works with the ballast, because the light not working could be bad bulbs, could be a bad ballast, and if not using actual florescent bulbs, having a ballast that the LED tube needs to run is just one more part to fail. And on a fixture with F40T12s, it's almost certainly quite an OLD part these days.
